# will it affect the laptop performance if I use the charger of other model

Tags: windows-7

Will it affect my laptop if I am using the different model charger cause the original charger was damage.The one I am using it right now has same capacity but it is of different model.

Comment: Also see: http://superuser.com/questions/629866/can-i-charge-my-laptop-with-a-charger-that-has-different-specifications

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the new charger supplies enough current (shown in "Amps" (it's fine if the new charger supplies more)) and the voltage is the same. If so then you will be perfectly fine. Although this may work, some laptops might have some adaptive charging technology which means you might notice a little change in charge time but nothing severe should occur.